# Localization in file shared using iTunes?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am developing Example which can share the file from iTunes.  Now my question is I have lots of file with `.txt` format in iTunes application Folder.  Data stored in file is like this:

"Name" = "standard" || "معيار" ;
"Price" = "$25.0" || "$ 25،0" ;

Now `Name = "Standard"` in English and other one is in Arabic language separated by the pipeline.  Now my question is how to display Arabic text in label in my application using Localization. I know how to perform localization in the application by making "en" ad "ar" files in `localizable.strings` but here the file I store in to iTunes and read the data from the file. 
At the end i want to make localization from the sharing file which have all files in a particular directory.